# How to use Threading in testNG annotations

Tags: java, multithreading, automation, testng

I need to use the below code in testNG framework using java, I am expecting that Thread should be executed before completing the code execution but the Thread is not getting executed fully and code is getting terminated. Is there any way I can execute the thread also before completing while execution.

```
package projects;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ThreadTest {


    @Test
    public static void afterMethod() throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.out.println("In After Class Method... ");
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                for(int i= 1; i< 10; i++)
                {
                    System.out.println("Printing: "+i);

                    try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException e) 
                    {e.printStackTrace();}
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();     

        System.out.println("Threading Bypassed... ");

    }

}
```

Comment: Well I meant to know how to complete a thread before shutting down the test.

Comment: Have you read the answer to the duplicate question? Just add a `thread.join()` at the last line of your test.

Comment: well I saw that and I used that too but thats not what I wanted, because if I am using thread.join() then I am executing the code sequentially whereas I wanted the Thread to be executed separately.

Comment: It is executed in parallel - join just waits for the thread to terminate... I don't really understand what you want...